# Итераторы на C++ , какие аналоги на C#?

Tags: c#, c++, итераторы

[Полный код на C++.](https://github.com/geidav/concave-poly-splitter/blob/master/polysplitter.cpp)

Есть код на C++:

```
std::list<PolyEdge>     SplitPoly;
struct PolyEdge
{
    PolyEdge(const QPointF &startPos, LineSide side) :
        StartPos(startPos),
        StartSide(side),
        Next(nullptr),
        Prev(nullptr),
        DistOnLine(0.0f),
        IsSrcEdge(false),
        IsDstEdge(false),
        Visited(false)
    {
    }

    QPointF             StartPos;   // start position on edge
    LineSide            StartSide;  // start position's side of split line
    PolyEdge *          Next;       // next polygon in linked list
    PolyEdge *          Prev;       // previous polygon in linked list
    float               DistOnLine; // distance relative to first point on split line
    bool                IsSrcEdge;  // for visualization
    bool                IsDstEdge;  // for visualization
    bool                Visited;    // for collecting split polygons
};    
...
// connect doubly linked list, except
// first->prev and last->next
// как этот код будет выглядеть на C#
for (auto iter=SplitPoly.begin(); iter!=std::prev(SplitPoly.end()); iter++)
{
    auto nextIter = std::next(iter);
    iter->Next = &(*nextIter);
    nextIter->Prev = &(*iter);
}
// как этот код будет выглядеть на C#
...
```

У меня код на C#:

```
public class PolyEdge
{
    public Vector2 StartPos;   // start position on edge
    public LineSide StartSide;  // start position's side of split line
    public PolyEdge Next;       // next polygon in linked list
    public PolyEdge Prev;       // previous polygon in linked list
    public float DistOnLine; // distance relative to first point on split line
    public bool IsSrcEdge;  // for visualization
    public bool IsDstEdge;  // for visualization
    public bool Visited;    // for collecting split polygons
    public PolyEdge(Vector2 _startPos, LineSide _side)
    {

        StartPos = _startPos;
        StartSide = _side;
        Next = Prev = null;
        DistOnLine = 0.0f;
        IsSrcEdge = IsDstEdge = Visited = false;

    }
};
static public List<ClippingOFArbitraryPolygons.PolyEdge> SplitPoly;
```

...

Как переписать этот участок на C++:

```
for (auto iter=SplitPoly.begin(); iter!=std::prev(SplitPoly.end()); iter++)
{
    auto nextIter = std::next(iter);
    iter->Next = &(*nextIter);
    nextIter->Prev = &(*iter);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < SplitPoly.Count - 1; i++) {
    SplitPoly[i].Next = SplitPoly[i + 1];
    SplitPoly[i + 1].Prev = SplitPoly[i];
}
```

Comment: проверок у первого и последнего объекта не надо? там же у них пусто будет у первого не будет  Prev  у последнего не будет Next

Comment: не всё дописал что перевести надо : SplitPoly[SplitPoly.Count - 1].Next  = SplitPoly[0];
        SplitPoly[0].Prev = SplitPoly[SplitPoly.Count - 1];

Comment: @IvanTriumphov вы этого и не просили делать

Comment: да я написал в комментариях )"не всё дописал что перевести надо"... спасибо